# NSWindow not closing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hey, SO, minor issue: I have an NSWindow I am using to report exceptions that works pretty well.  I give the user the option to quit the application or continue running in an uncertain state with a "Continue" button.  The "Continue" button is supposed to simply close the window, however it does not work.  Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) continueOperation:(id)sender
{
    [[self window] performClose:self];
}
```

If the user presses the close X in the upper left corner, the window closes correctly, but the code does not do the trick.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: [[self view] window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `[self window]` is returning the window that you think it is?

Comment: Wait, what?  If my NSWindowController is receiving the -continueOperation: message, which other window could it possibly be?

Comment: Huh, so turns out window is nil.  And IB is not giving me the ability to link the window.  Wut do?

Comment: Solved it!  So I disconnected the button from File's Owner, and move the action to performClose: on the window itself.  Not sure why I can't get access to the window in IB or why the window is not set using `-initWithNibName:` in my NSWindowController subclass.  Weird.  Thanks anyway!